# Как подойти к решению задачи связанной с машинным зрением?

Tags: python, искусственный-интеллект

Учусь на программиста. Встал вопрос дипломной работы. Предложили тему - "анализ уровня опасности окружающей обстановки для незрячих людей". В итоге приложение должно оценивать уровень опасности по видео потоку камеры и параллельно оповещать пользователя звуковым сигналом. Сказали, что тема сложная и ее хватит даже на магистерскую работу.

Нткнулся в интернете на видео о том, как ориентируются дроны по точкам интереса, отслеживая их, отностельное друг-друг, перемешение. Пока думаю двигаться в этом направлении.

Собственно, прошу поделиться теоретическим материалом на данную тему, книги, статьи, видео. Вообще, правильный ли подход я выбираю? Возможно у кого то будут идеии отностилено технологии реализации. Прошу оценить сложность поставленной задачи. И вообще пишите любые комментарии, касаемо данной темы.

Comment: [Тут](https://dou.ua/forums/topic/25111/) куча всего по computer vision